# Preferred way to assign a class member of type std::function during runtime?

Tags: c++

I want to store function pointers to members functions in a `std::function` object. They all have the same signature. The condition, stored in the member `status_`, for which a member function should be called is found at runtime from a config file or CLI flag. However, `status_` is set once during initialization and doesn't change after that. But the member functions are called many times, maybe around 1000.

```cpp
class Product
{

public:

        Product(int status);

        void runJob(const ProductState& state) ;

        // The possible jobs
        // ----------------------------------
        void create(const ProductState& state) ;

        void repair(const ProductState& state) ;

        void deploy(const ProductState& state) ;

        void change(const ProductState& state) ;

private:

        int status_ ;
        std::function<void(const ProductState&)> jobRunner_ ;
};
```

Which is the preferred way to store the function?

1. Using lambdas

```cpp
// In the Product(int status) constructor
Product::Product(int status)
{
        status_ = status ;

        if (status_ == 0) {
          jobRunner_ = [this](const ProductState& state) {this->create(state);} ;
        } else if (status_ == 1) {
          jobRunner_ = [this](const ProductState& state) {this->repair(state);} ;
        } else if (status_ == 2) {
          jobRunner_ = [this](const ProductState& state) {this->deploy(state);} ;
        }
}

void Product::runJob(const ProductState& state)
{
        jobRunner_(state) ;
}
```

Or

2. using `std::bind` and `std::placeholders`

```cpp
// In the Product(int status) constructor
Product::Product(int status)
{
        status_ = status ;

        if (status_ == 0) {
          jobRunner_ = std::bind(&Product::create, this, std::placeholders::_1);
        } else if (status_ == 1) {
          jobRunner_ = std::bind(&Product::repair, this, std::placeholders::_1);
        } else if (status_ == 2) {
          jobRunner_ = std::bind(&Product::deploy, this, std::placeholders::_1);
        }
}

void Product::runJob(const ProductState& state)
{
        jobRunner_(state) ;
}
```

Another options is check the `status_` everytime inside `runJob()` which removes the need for the `jobRunner_` member but I believe it is slower as it is checked 1000 times as compared to only checking it once during initialization.

```cpp
void Product::runJob(const ProductState& state)
{
        if (status_ == 0) {
          create(state);
        } else if (status_ == 1) {
          repair(state);
        } else if (status_ == 2) {
          deploy(state);
        }
}
```

Comment: or 3, directly in a variable as pointer to member function? (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access).

Comment: @TooTone How is it better from the first approach using `std:;function` objects?

Comment: I prefer option one, but `std::function` does have a performance penalty.  The checks in option 3 might out perform it.  Only way to truly know is to profile/benchmark the code.

Comment: @RaZ0rr It should be there as an option, at least. I would prefer it, as it's direct + expresses the constraint that all the functions you're calling have the same signature. `std::function` is more general but that isn't needed here imo.

Comment: @RaZ0rr Why creating a lambda that only calls a function? Just call the function through a pointer to it. Isn't it more direct?

Comment: @TooTone Thanks for the tip. I hadn't even considered it because I thought `std::function` is the "C++" way.

Comment: don't use `std::bind` if you don't need to. Its return type is unspecified and has extreme quirks that can be rather surprising, eg "If some of the arguments that are supplied in the call to g() are not matched by any placeholders stored in g, the unused arguments are evaluated and discarded." (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès To be honest, I thought `std::function` does more or less the same thing. I'll look into it more. Thanks.

Comment: @RaZ0rr The problem with `std::function` is that it uses type erasure which requires dynamic memory allocation and you pay a performance penalty above and beyond the cost of indirection through a pointer.

Comment: @NathanOliver Like any engineering thing there is a choice to make. Does the performance drop balance against other benefits like ease of use/maintainability. So I wouldn't say it is a problem, but just an ascpect to take into consideration at design time

Comment: please try to compile code before posting it. You define the constructor twice, all functions are missing the return type and `ProductState` is not declared. I am nitpicking on details, but such details distract from the actual question and make it unecessarily harder to write an answer. See also [mcve]

Comment: @PepjinKramer I tend to put expressivenes before performance. And using the least powerful tool to get a job done usually helps with both. OP does not need a type-erased function wrapper, but thats what `std::function` is

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Fair comments :)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Thanks for the heads up. I cleaned it. The constructor is not defined twice, I was providing two scenarios in my question. The remaining variables I made verbose because their definition doesn't have any impact on the answer

Comment: @RaZ0rr `Product(int status) {} ;` is a definition and then in the two scenarios you define it again

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai  Yes, Once again thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `std::bind` unless you need to. Its the ancient way to do things that now you can do much simpler with lamdba expressions.

Don't use `std::function` whenver you need to store a function. `std::function`s main purpose is to do type-erasure. One `std::function` can store any kind of callables, free function, lambdas, and more. If you want to store different callables that are all of the same type, you do not need `std::function`.

As mentioned in a comment you should consider to use a pointer to member function:

```
struct ProductState {};

class Product {

public:
        Product(int status) ;
        void runJob(const ProductState& state) ;
        void create(const ProductState& state) ;
        void repair(const ProductState& state) ;
        void deploy(const ProductState& state) ;
        void change(const ProductState& state) ;

private:

        int status_ ;
        using job_type = void(Product::*)(const ProductState&);
        job_type job;
};


Product::Product(int status) {
        status_ = status ;

        if (status_ == 0) {
          job = &Product::repair;
        } else if (status_ == 1) {
          job = &Product::create;
        } else if (status_ == 2) {
          job = &Product::deploy;
        } else {
          job = &Product::change;
        }
}

void Product::runJob(const ProductState& state)
{
        (this->*job)(state);
}
```

And if you actually do need `std::function`, using a lambda is fine.

Comment: `std::function` has the same problem as `std::endl`: folks read the name but don't pay attention to what it actually does. Programming by pun... +1.

Comment: @PeteBecker imho the name is really unfortunate, I mean it could have been `function_wrapper` or similar which would at least suggest that it does something extra, but just `function` sounds like  -bam- totally clear, thats what you use when you need a function

Comment: If "std::bind is ancient" why was `std::bind_front` just introduced?

Comment: @BenVoigt Because they are supposed to replace `std::bind`. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind_front#Notes. They fix some of the quirks (at the cost of flexibility) eg this one https://godbolt.org/z/4Wq7TcY4n